# Problems with 2 homogeneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

[image]

Hello friends. I do not see at the moment how to solve it.
Thank you

Comment: First one is not homogeneous and i can't understand the second one

Answer (score 3):

For the first one you can set $u=y+x$. So, you get $$y'=(y+x)^2\longrightarrow u'-1=u^2$$ which is separable OE. For the second OE firstly write it as follows:

$$y'-\frac{x}{1-x^2}y=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ and now use a proper integrating factor regarding to the following formula:
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int\frac{x}{-1+x^2}dx\right)$$

Comment: For the first one, $u=x+y\implies u'=1+y'$. Hence $y'=(x+y)^2$ becomes $ u'-1=u^2$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for saying so. I want to be like Daady-Long-Legs. Down to earth  and useful for others. Exactly, as many do here in this site. Like you!

Comment: Hello friends and thank you for your fast support.

Comment: I have one more equation,that I want to solve:

Comment: y'=x^2+y^2
I know, that this is a kind of Riccatti equation, but is it possible to solve it with only simple methods?
Thank you

Comment: @Eu2718: Sorry for the delay in response. Actually, the Ricatti's OE is always taught when we face to First-ODE so the way which I don't know any other *simple* method.